# Sun Lamp not shining through Glass

Tags: light, transparency, glass

I've set up my first scene in experimenting with lighting and glass, and at one point I managed to have the Sun lamp object shine through the windows and cast intense shadow inside the room. This was exactly what I wanted. However, in trying to switch to 'Cycles' mode, my PC crashed. I lost those few hours of work. No big deal, except I can't make the transparency work again.

Emission objects seem to pass their light through the glass, but the Sun lamp I set up isn't. This is really frustrating! Image is attached for reference of nodes used (yes, it's Principled BDSF but I used a Glass node earlier and it still didn't work as intended.) I really would love some help[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in eevee you can use this setup:

-> important is the blend and shadow mode of the material.

[image]

if you then toggle to cycles, it works as well:

[image]

and here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Man, I just deleted an object I had making emission light and bam, the shadows are back! Everything is fine! Thank you for helping, I was getting incredibly frustrated!